# Prevent margins from pushing elements out of container

Tags: html, css, margin

I am having trouble fitting three inline-blocks (black) inside a container (gray) with fixed width. These blocks have margins (orange), and the problem is that the last block is pushed into the next row even though the actual element (black) is still inside its container (gray).

I want blocks to be pushed into the next line when the actual block is outside the container, not the margins. How can i do this?

**Reference image:**
[image]

Edit: A workaround I found was to wrap the blocks into another container with enough width to cover the right margins.

Comment: A demo or it didn't happen. :D

Comment: Really? That's not a default behaviour?

Comment: Yes, default behavior, but each situation is different. `inline-block` displays like words, with gaps between. There are various ways to remove the gaps. Either remove the whitespace between elements or try this method: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/BfIun/

Comment: It didn't seem to work. By the way, the margins are put by me intentionally. I want the gaps. I just don't want the blocks to be pushed into the next row when only the gap is outside the container.

Comment: @ralph.m: Whitespace and margins are two different things.

Comment: Anyway we need to see how the margins are set up in order to determine a good workaround. That means CSS (and possibly HTML), not just a screenshot.

Comment: `Whitespace and margins are two different things`. I know, but the question doesn't really make clear which is the main issue, if not both. I read it one way on first reading, then differently on the second (and thus the answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the margin on the left of each box instead, and then pull the box wrapper to the left with a negative margin. E.g. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/Hesgu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
section {width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; background: #f7f7f7;}
article {margin-left: -20px;}
div {width: 200px; height: 100px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; background: black;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <article>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Here is the improved fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CKQLE/3/

Few key styles here are:

`text-align: justify;` on the container to evenly distribute the elements within the containing element.

`font-size: 0;` to remove whitespace that comes with inline block elements.

And this block:

```
.container:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to handle overflow of elements.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know which one is the last element (there are more blocks and rows). Also responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox model instead inline-block, i include an example in jsfiddle with crossbrowser:

```
display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

You can play with width of the stage to get a responsive results
[http://jsfiddle.net/X5pg7/](http://jsfiddle.net/X5pg7/1/)

Comment: This solution looks neat. But I haven't seen any sites with grid layout using it, maybe because of the limited browser support?

Comment: This article ilustrate how to Mixing Old and New for the Best Browser Support with Flexbo http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/